# Is it possible for PHP to write additional PHP functions like a Lisp macro?

Tags: php, macros

I'm writing a unit testing platform and I want to be able to dynamically generate a function based off of each function in the web service I am testing. The dynamic function would be generated with default(correct) values for each argument in the web service and allow them to be easily traded out with incorrect values for error testing.

```
$arrayOfDefVals = array(123, 'foo');

testFunctionGenerator('function1', $arrayOfDefVals);

//resulting php code:
function1Test($expectedOutput, $arg1=123, $arg2='foo')
{
    try
    {
        $out = function1($arg1, $arg2);
        if($expectedOutput === $out)
            return true;
        else
            return $out;
    } 
    catch ($e) 
    {
        return $e;
    } 
}
```

This would allow me to quickly and cleanly pass one bad argument, or any number of bad arguments, at a time to test all of the error catching in the web service.

My main question is:
Is this even possible with php?
If it's not possible, is there an alternative?

**EDIT**: I'm not looking for a unit test, I'm trying to learn by doing. I'm not looking for advice on this code example, it's just a quick example of what I would like to do. I just want to know if it's possible.

Comment: What if the function exits or outputs some sort of error rather than returning a result for bad input?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you writing a unit testing platform, rather than using one that already exists?

Comment: … namely http://www.phpunit.de/

Comment: This is just a quick example, there are a lot of other things I would have it do as well. The question is whether or not it's possible.

Comment: I'm not asking about the unit test. I know there are other ones out there. The question is can php use macros like lisp does.

Comment: you can use `create_function` which is basically an `eval` in sheep's clothes.

Comment: Apart from that, PHP5.3 als has Lambdas and Closures. On a sidenote, I dont understand the code you show.

Comment: @phizzle: I added an answer, however you changed your macro. But you might still see what it's about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not try that first as PHP has not build-in macro support. But probably something in that direction:

```
function function1($param1, $param2)
{
    return  sprintf("param1: %d, param2: '%s'\n", $param1, $param2);
}

/* Macro: basically a port of your macro as a function */

$testFunctionGenerator = function($callback, array $defVals = array())
{
    $defVals = array_values($defVals); // list, not hash
    return function() use ($callback, $defVals)
    {
        $callArgs = func_get_args();
        $expectedOutput = array_shift($callArgs);

        $callArgs += $defVals;

        return $expectedOutput == call_user_func_array($callback, $callArgs);
    };
};

/* Use */

$arrayOfDefVals = array(123, 'foo');

$function1Test = $testFunctionGenerator('function1', $arrayOfDefVals);

var_dump($function1Test("param1: 456, param2: 'foo'\n", 456)); # bool(true)
```

Probably this is helpful, see [*Anonymous functions<sup>­Docs</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), [`func_get_args`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/func_get_args), the [*Union array operator<sup>­Docs</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) and [`call_user_func_array`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/call_user_func_array).

Comment: I know this wasn't in my question, but for future reference: Since I was using SoapClient() I was not able to use call_user_func_array, I had to instead use $client->__soapCall($callback, $arrayOfArgs) which is basically the same thing, only it actually works with web services.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, you can set default parameters in functions:

```
function function1Test($expectedOutput, $testArg1=123, $testArg2='foo') {
   ...
}
```

Beyond that, I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve with this "function generator"...

Comment: I am trying to avoid having to write each test function individually. With a macro I can just give it a list of functions from the web service, and will then have a list of test functions.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

This example from the manual should get you on the right track:

```
<?php
call_user_func(function($arg) { print "[$arg]\n"; }, 'test'); /* As of PHP 5.3.0 */
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a function you have file access to (i.e., it's not a part of the PHP standard library and you have permissions to read from the file), you could do something like this:

Assume we have a function like this located in some file. The file will have to be included (i.e., the function will have to be in PHP's internal symbol table):

```
function my_original_function($param1, $param2)
{
    echo "$param1 $param2 \n";
}
```

Use the ReflectionFunction class to get details about that function and where it's defined: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php.

$reflection = new ReflectionFunction('my_original_function');

Next, you can use the reflection instance to get the path to that file, the first/last line number of the function, and the parameters to the function:

```
$file_path = $reflection->getFileName();
$start_line = $reflection->getStartLine();
$end_line = $reflection->getEndLine();
$params = $reflection->getParameters();
```

Using these, you could:

1. read the function out of the file into a string
2. rewrite the first line to change the function name, using the known function name as a reference
3. rewrite the first line to alter the parameter defaults, using $params as a reference
4. write the altered function string to a file
5. include the file
6. Voila! You now have the new function available.

Depending on what it is you're *actually* trying to accomplish, you could also potentially just use ReflectionFunction::getClosure() to get an closure copy of the function, assign it to whatever variable you want, and define the parameters there. See: http://us.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php. Or you could instantiate multiple ReflectionFunctions and call ReflectionFunction::invoke()/invokeArgs() with the parameter set you want. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunction.invokeargs.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunction.invoke.php